# Jquery/Ajax Drag n Drop to CLICK function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

first of all, take a look at this demo: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/shopping-cart-php-jquery/demo.php
taken from tutorialzine.com

i've already taken that and used in my project now, shopping cart. no errors so far drag n drop is really cute. what im trying to make is that, the items/products can also be clickable. im still new in jquery/ajax stuffs so its so hard for me to make it clickable instead of dragging and dropping it in cart.

here's the code inside script.js which contains drag/drop function:

```
var purchased=new Array();  //an array containing all the products we've purchased so far
var totalprice=0;   //the total price

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.product').simpletip({   //using the simpletip plugin

        offset:[40,0],
        content:'<img style="margin:10px;" src="img/ajax_load.gif" alt="loading" />',   // default content
        onShow: function(){

            var param = this.getParent().find('img').attr('src');
            // fix for IE6
            if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=='6.0')
            {
                param = this.getParent().find('img').attr('style').match(/src=\"([^\"]+)\"/);
                param = param[1];
            }

            // after the tooltip is shown, load the tips.php file and pass the image name as a parameter
            this.load('ajax/tips.php',{img:param});
        } 

    });

    $(".product img").draggable({   // enable all product images to be dragged

    containment: 'document',
    opacity: 0.6,
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 100

    });

    $("div.content.drop-here").droppable({  // convert the shopping cart to a droppable

            drop:
                function(e, ui)
                {
                    var param = $(ui.draggable).attr('src');
                    // IE6 fix
                    if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=='6.0')
                    {
                        param = $(ui.draggable).attr('style').match(/src=\"([^\"]+)\"/);
                        param = param[1];
                    }

                    addlist(param); // the special addlist function - see below
                }

    });

});
```

second part of script.js:

```
function addlist(param)
{
    // the addlist function ads a product to the shopping cart

    $.ajax({    // sending an ajax request to addtocart.php
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/addtocart.php",
    data: 'img='+encodeURIComponent(param), // the product image as a parameter
    dataType: 'json',   // expecting json
    beforeSend: function(x){$('#ajax-loader').css('visibility','visible');},    // showing the loading gif
    success: function(msg){

        $('#ajax-loader').css('visibility','hidden');   // hiding the loading gif animation
        if(parseInt(msg.status)!=1)
        {
            return false;   // if there has been an error, return false
        }
        else
        {
            var check=false;
            var cnt = false;

            for(var i=0; i<purchased.length;i++)
            {
                if(purchased[i].id==msg.id) // find if we have already bought this prduct
                {
                    check=true;
                    cnt=purchased[i].cnt;

                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!cnt)    // if we haven't bought it yet, or we have removed it from the purchases, we insert it in the shopping cart
                $('#item-list').append(msg.txt);

            if(!check)  // if we haven't bought it yet, insert it in the purchased array
            {
                purchased.push({id:msg.id,cnt:1,price:msg.price});
            }

            else    // else if we've bought it
            {
                if(cnt>=3) return false;    // 3 products of type max

                purchased[i].cnt++;
                $('#'+msg.id+'_cnt').val(purchased[i].cnt); // update the select box
            }

            totalprice+=msg.price;  // recalculate the price
            update_total(); // update the total div

        }

        $('.tooltip').hide();   // hiding the tooltip (sometimes it stays on screen after the drag)

    }
    });
}

function findpos(id)    // a helper function that finds the position at which the product is inserted in the array, returns the position
{
    for(var i=0; i<purchased.length;i++)
    {
        if(purchased[i].id==id)
            return i;
    }

    return false;
}

function remove(id) // remove a product from the shopping cart
{
    var i=findpos(id);  // find its position in the array

    totalprice-=purchased[i].price*purchased[i].cnt;    // recalculate the price
    purchased[i].cnt = 0;   // reset the counter

    $('#table_'+id).remove();   // remove it from the cart
    update_total(); // update the total price counter on the page
}

function change(id) // evoked when we change the number of products via the select area
{
    var i=findpos(id);

    totalprice+=(parseInt($('#'+id+'_cnt').val())-purchased[i].cnt)*purchased[i].price;

    purchased[i].cnt=parseInt($('#'+id+'_cnt').val());
    update_total();
}

function update_total() // function that updates the total price div on the page
{
    if(totalprice)
    {
        $('#total').html('total: $'+totalprice);    // if we've bought somehitng, show the total price div and the purchase button
        $('a.button').css('display','block');
    }
    else    // hide them
    {
        $('#total').html('');
        $('a.button').hide();
    }
}
```

aside from drag n drop function i also want to make the item clickable, click the item/product and it will appear in the shopping cart :( any help posible..thanks in advance

Comment: SO isn't a free coding service, what have you tried in order to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you'll have to chose between the drag & drop and the click behaviour.
Trying to implemente both would confuse your users and make your code diffucult to adapt. But to answer your question, here is how you could do to enable the click on your elements :

The best option would be to set a link on your image :

```
<a href="addToCart.php?id=78"><img.....></a>
```

This could work in ajax to.

If you still wish to implement both drag & drop and click, you should consider separate the display of the two functions : one zone to enable the drag on click, and another to add directly the product to the cart :

```
<img ... alt="click to drag !"><br>
<a href="#">Click to add to cart !</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering guys. though i didn't get any xD

but..

i've figured it out ! yay!

this is one for click function:

$('.product img').click(function(){
var param = $(this).attr('src'); if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=='6.0') { param = $(this).attr('style').match(/src=\"([^\"]+)\"/); param = param[1]; }
addlist(param); });

now it is both clickable and draggable :D